# Accessing members of a matrix in HLSL

Tags: matrix, direct3d, hlsl

I am a bit new to using Direct3D and HLSL and I was wondering about the following: How would one access a member of a matrix in one of the shader functions. It seems to me that it should be the dot operator and some stuff after that just as with the vectors. However, I am not exactly sure what I would put down after the dot if I were to use it. Would it be something like .m12 to access the member of the 2nd row and 3rd column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you matrix  is

```
float4x4 myTransform;
```

You can access members 1-based (eg m11 to m44) like :

```
float member = myTransform._11;
float member = myTransform._44;
```

or zero based as:

```
float member = myTransform._m00;
float member = myTransform._m33;
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to catflier's answer. You can also use array subscript syntax (zero based) like you would expect in C++ to get matrix members.

```
float4x4 myMatrix;
float x = myMatrix[0][1];
```